# ¿Por que mi Entidad no guarda todas las propiedades en BD?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, java-8, spring-data

Tengo mi clase `Student` con las propiedades de ID, First Name, Last Name, Email, Date of Birth y **Year**. Los datos los recibo por medio de un formulario HTML, todos los datos se reciben y almacenan en mi BD de MySQL perfectamente menos la propiedad de **Year**, la cual es calculada a partir de Date of Birth. He intendado asignar el valor por medio de `this.year = metodo` pero tampoco funcionó, y por medio del **setter** tampoco funciona.

Les dejo el código de la clase en concreto. Estoy utilizando Spring-Boot y Spring Data JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Email
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "day_birth")
private String dateOfBirth;

@Column(name = "year")
private Integer year;

public Student() {
}

public Student(@NotEmpty String firstName, @NotEmpty String lastName
        , @Email String email,@NotEmpty String dateOfBirth) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.setYear(parseBirth(dateOfBirth));
}

/********** GETTERS / SETTERS ***********/

////////// ID////////////

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

////////// FIRST NAME////////////

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

////////// LAST NAME////////////

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

////////// EMAIL////////////

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

////////// BIRHT////////////
public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}


////////// YEAR////////////
public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}


public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}


/**
 * @return LocalDate
 * 
 *         metodo auxiliar, convierte el String dateOfBirth en un LocalDate para
 *         luego poder calcular la edad
 */
private static Integer parseBirth(String dateOfBirth) {


    Integer primero = dateOfBirth.indexOf('-');
    Integer segundo = dateOfBirth.lastIndexOf('-');

    Integer year = Integer.parseInt(dateOfBirth.substring(0, primero));
    Integer month = Integer.parseInt(dateOfBirth.substring(primero+1, segundo));
    Integer day = Integer.parseInt(dateOfBirth.substring(segundo+1, dateOfBirth.length()));

    LocalDate birth = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    LocalDate localDateNow = LocalDate.now();
    
    Period periodo = Period.between(birth, localDateNow);
    
    return (Integer) periodo.getYears();
}
}
```

El método que calcula la edad funciona correctamente ya que lo he testeado, pero en algún punto se pierde la información ya que no se almacena en la BD.

Dejo una imagen del test y como al acceder por medio del método **Getter** me devuelve el valor correcto.

[image: test]

Comment: Hola Joel, el codigo Java parece bien. debes revisar que la columna en la BD en efecto se llame 'year', tambien verifica que la columna de la fecha tenga el nombre correcto y se reciba de la forma correcta al hacer GET o POST

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya revise el tema de los nombres y esta todo ok, probé en guardar un objeto manualmente, desde el main de la app, y en ese caso me lo guarda en la bd a la propiedad con el valor correspondiente, pero desde la web no hay caso, todas las demás propiedades las recibe y procesa de manera correcta

Comment: Yo revisaría que le import fuera el de java time, porque hallé en google otro método que regresa una lista. Quita tu conversión explícita a integer, que como saber permite nulos y ve si te marca error.

Comment: Joel intenta cambiando el nombre del campo "year" tal vez es una palabra reservada en el motor de BD y por eso no lo guarda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era mas profundo, se trataba de que mi constructor de Students no recibe el parámetro de Year, así que al momento de hacer la persistencia de datos con la BD no tomaba y no lo guardaba, la solución fácil es settear el valor dentro de sett de otra propiedad EJ: private void setDateOfBirth (...){this.year = ....}, también podría utilizar la anotación @PrePersistence y ahí hacer la asignación, pero en esta opción si yo quiero hacer un up-date de la fecha de nacimiento no me actualiza la edad también, dependiendo de la necesidades se pueden implementar diferentes soluciones.